# Angularjs $http deleting data from server

Tags: eclipse, angularjs, http, playframework

i need to delete a received data from "play" server by using angularjs.

I'm using a "play" server and eclipse to save the data on server.

script.js (adding item)

```
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
//---Add car---//
    $scope.addCar = function() {
        $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : "http://localhost:9000/addCar",
            params : {
                manufacture : $scope.manufacturer.name,
                year : $scope.year.name,
                number : $scope.number,
                model : $scope.model,
                price : $scope.price,
                color : $scope.myColor.name,
                engine : $scope.engine.name
            }
        });
        alert("Car Successfuly added!");
    };
```

Application.java (adding function to arrayList)

```
public static Result addCar(String manufacture, String year, String number, String model, String price, String color, String engine)
    {
        response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        Car c = new Car(manufacture, year, number, model, price, color, engine);
        cars.add(c);
        return ok(Json.toJson(cars));
    }
```

script.js (Getting data from server) here i can use `<tr ng-repeat="car in cars">` and print all cars in page

```
    //---Get car---//
        $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : "http://localhost:9000/getCars"
        }).success(function(data) {
            $scope.cars = data;
 });
```

Application.java (getting json)

```
public static Result getCars()
    {
        response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        return ok(Json.toJson(cars));
    }
```

After this i can put my data on html page

```
<h1>Car list</h1>
<div ng:controller="myCtrl">
    <table class="table">
        <tr ng-repeat="car in cars">
            <td>{{car.manufacture}}</td>
            <td>{{car.year}}</td>
            <td>{{car.number}}</td>
            <td>{{car.model}}</td>
            <td>{{car.price}}</td>
            <td>{{car.color}}</td>
            <td>{{car.engine}}</td>
            <td>[<a href ng:click="removeItem($index)">X</a>]
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

How i can delete item (car) from data(cars) like here:

```
$scope.removeItem = function(index) {
        //This code deleting data from page, not from server
        $scope.cars.splice(index, 1);
    };
});
```

{edit}

im trying to do something like this:

in script.js

```
$scope.removeItem = function() {
        $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : "http://localhost:9000/removeCar",
            params : {
                manufacture : $scope.manufacturer.name,
                year : $scope.year.name,
                number : $scope.number,
                model : $scope.model,
                price : $scope.price,
                color : $scope.myColor.name,
                engine : $scope.engine.name
            }
        });
        alert("Car Successfuly deleted!");
    };
```

in Application.java

```
public static Result removeCar(String manufacture, String year, String number, String model, String price, String color, String engine)
    {
        response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        Car c = new Car(manufacture, year, number, model, price, color, engine);

        for(int i=0; i<cars.size();i++)
            if(cars.get(i).equals(c)){
                cars.remove(i);
            }
        return ok(Json.toJson(cars));
    }
```

but its not working

Comment: Just write another method in your service for deleting the car by passing in the car id and call it, just like you did for other things.

Comment: Small suggestions, whenever you modify your resource - use POST/UPDATE/DELETE methods accordingly. GET should stay idempotent. It is good for read operations.

Comment: i cant write another method, i don't know how i can send an object to Application.java and delete this obj in arraylist with id or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `track by`

```
<tr ng-repeat="car in cars track by $index">
```

`track by` will associate the objects in the collection with the DOM elements.

[edit]

To delete from server, pass the object Id rather than the index (you probably need to create an Id, or use the Id that the database uses).

```
<td>[<a href ng:click="removeItem({{car.id}})">X</a>]
```

Then in your controller you need to do a POST request to the server.

```
$scope.removeCar = function(id) {
    $http({
        method : "POST",
        url : "http://localhost:9000/removeCar",
        params : {
            id : id
        }
    });
    alert("Car Successfuly removed!");
};
```

On your server you need to inspect the request body to get the Id, since you're doing a post request (no parameters).

```
public static Result removeCar() {
        // Look at the request to get the Id
        request().body().asJson();
        // Then remove from database
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but how it can help me? I need to send an object to-                                                         " public static Result removeCar() " (remove function)             and remove this object by something from  my array list:            " private static ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>(); "

Comment: Like someone else suggested, use IDs. Then pass the ID to your server and remove the object from your database.

Comment: The problem was my database is (ArrayList<Car> cars) and i can't pass there with id.

Comment: You can iterate through the ArrayList and when you find the object with the Id, remove it.

Comment: user2730785 Thank you, your answer is useful!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!! You all helped me a lot!!!

This is my decision (deleting car by number)-

html

```
<tr ng-repeat="car in cars track by $index">
            <td>{{car.manufacture}}</td>
            <td>{{car.year}}</td>
            <td>{{car.number}}</td>
            <td>{{car.model}}</td>
            <td>{{car.price}}</td>
            <td>{{car.color}}</td>
            <td>{{car.engine}}</td>
            <td>[<a href ng:click="removeItem(car.number)">X</a>]
            </td>
        </tr>
```

script

```
//---Remove car---//
    $scope.removeItem = function(number) {
        $http({
            method : "POST",
            url : "http://localhost:9000/removeCar",
            params : {
                number : number
            }
        });
        alert("Car Successfuly deleted!");
```

java

```
public static Result removeCar(String number)
    {
        response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        for(int i = 0; i<cars.size(); i++){
            if(cars.get(i).getNumber().equals(number)){
                cars.remove(i);
            }
        }
        return ok(Json.toJson(cars));
    }
```